# Why VB Script call to WCF works only when Fiddler is running

Tags: wcf, vbscript, wsdl, fiddler, soap-client

I have this strange behavior and I just can't figure it out. I have very simple VB Script using SoapClient and talks to a WCF Endpoint. Please see below.

```
Dim oPPWS As Object
Set oPPWS = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")

Const URL = "http://localhost:57660/Service1.svc?wsdl"
oPPWS.MSSoapInit URL

Dim strResp As String
strResp = oPPWS.GetData()
```

This code works perfectly "**only**" when [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is running. Otherwise I get the below error on oPPWS.MSSoapInit URL

> "WSDLReader:XML Parser failed at linenumber 0, lineposition 0, reason
>   is: The download of the specified resource has failed.  HRESULT=0x1:
>   Incorrect function.
>    - WSDLReader:Loading of the WSDL file failed HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect."

I think the Fiddler act as a proxy to the WCF call and make it somehow connect to the service.
But I just don't know / can't explain exactly why. Has anyone seen this before? Also is there a way to get this code working without this behavior?

I'm also running on Windows 8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure this out. 
It was my IE proxy settings causing it to not to work. Once I turn off the IE proxy settings, whether having the Fiddler opened or not, the above script works.
I think the Fiddler ignore the IE proxy settings? May be but I don't know.

The way I found this issue is using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)
It shows the request failed because the Proxy access id denied

Spent few hours for nothing and hopefully this would save time for someone else :)

Comment: Fiddler adopts the system's proxy settings when it starts. If those settings are bogus and point to a proxy that doesn't exist, the system settings are ignored and a note is made on Fiddler's `Log` tab.